# What is the interval of convergence of : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{n!}x^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$x+ \frac{2^2x^2}{2!}+ \frac{3^3x^3}{3!}+ \frac{4^4x^4}{4!}+...$

> Possible answers-

**1.($0,1/e$)**

**2.(1/e, $\infty$)**

**3.(2/e, 3/e)**

**4.(3/e, 4/e)**

```
My answer is not matching
```

$u_n= \frac{n^nx^n}{n!}$,$u_{n+1}= \frac{{(n+1)}^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Applying ratio test,we get

$\vert \frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} \vert$=$\vert $ $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n $($\frac{1}{x} $)$ \vert$,

from this we get $\vert ex \vert<1$ i.e.,$\vert x \vert<1/
e$ as $n $ tends to infinity

need help!!

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Unless it is given $\;x>0\;$ and thus option (1) is the correct one, I think none of the options is the correct one...

Comment: @DonAntonio:you're correct because (1) is the interval  which is part of (-1/e,1/e),so the best possible answer is (1).

Comment: @PKStyles It looks that way, yet it is odd they didn't say $\;x>0\;$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @lab bhattacharjee, one may use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test), as $n \to \infty$, giving
$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \to e.
$$

Can you take it from here?